# How to get sum of value from Json Array in Vue

Tags: vuejs3

My json array is

```html
"test": [
    {
      "name": "item1",
      "value": "440"
    },
    {
      "name": "item2",
      "value": "220"
    },
    {
      "name": "item3",
      "value": "46"
    }
  ]
```

I'm calling function from template as

```html
<template>
  <td>{{ calculateSumofValues(test) }}</td>
</template>
```

Script function is

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  const calculateSumofValues = (test?:Object) => {
    console.log("test", test)
    // calculate sum of values 
  };
</script>
```

**I want to calculate total values of every item on the array (440+220+46 = 706)**
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: For best results, please show real code, and show it as code-formatted text. This includes showing the pertinent JSON data, as well as your [mre] Vue instance with both `<template>` and `<script>` sections, and use this information and your own code attempt at a solution to help make your question more specific, easier to answer and more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: I'm guessing that you will want to create and display computed values based on a ref that holds your JSON array, but I can't tell for sure as yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to do something over every element in an array and accumulate results somehow, useful for summing over values in the array.

```js
const test = [{
    "name": "item1",
    "value": "440"
  },
  {
    "name": "item2",
    "value": "220"
  },
  {
    "name": "item3",
    "value": "46"
  }
]



const calculateSumofValues = (test) => {
  console.log("test", test)

  return test.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + parseInt(cur.value), 0)
};

console.log(calculateSumofValues(test))
```